# Get the Top 5 of each distinct column value

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

Lets say there was a dataset like this

```
Grp   | Name (Unique)
A     | Joe
B     | Bob
C     | Jill
B     | James
```

If there were about 50 of each group (A,B,C) how do I return a result with only the top 5 from each group without doing something like this

```
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE WHERE Grp = 'A' UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE WHERE Grp = 'B' UNION ALL
SELECT TOP 5 * FROM TABLE WHERE Grp = 'C'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Try

```
SELECT Grp, Name FROM(
 SELECT Grp, Name, RANK() OVER (Partition By Grp ORDER By Name DESC) as rankname
   FROM YourTable)
    WHERE rankname <= 5
```

Edit: I think this is what you want. If it's not, just comment and we can work on it.

Comment: Scotch beat me to it. :) See also http://weblogs.sqlteam.com/jeffs/archive/2007/03/30/More-SQL-Server-2005-Solutions.aspx

Answer (score 0):

I had to name the first select to get it to work.

```
SELECT Grp, Name FROM (
  SELECT Grp, Name, RANK() OVER (Partition By Grp ORDER By Name DESC) as rankname FROM YourTable ) A
WHERE A.rankname <= 5
```